# Where do Typescript Node Module Implementations live

Tags: typescript, npm, typescript-definitions

So I am writing an application using Typescript. I am using the following library;

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/request`

So I ran `npm install --save @types/request` and decided to inspect my `node_modules` folder. In it I can see the request library with these files:

[image]

In typescript, files that end with `.d.ts` are definition files, where implementation does not exist.

When I actually write my code, I am able to import from this library and use it's API just fine. But where does the implementation for this API actually live, it does not appear to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `request` NPM package: https://github.com/request/request. The [@types/request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/request) package is only TypeScript definitions for it. If a package itself does not have TypeScript definitions, TypeScript will look for them in `@types/packageName`.

```
npm i --save request

import * as request from 'request'
```